# Existence of a holomorphic function when the plane cancels a Hausdorff dimension 1 set

Tags: complex-analysis, dimension-theory-analysis

(a) Show that there does not exist a holomorphic function $f$ on $\mathbb C \backslash \{1, -1\}$ so that
$$f'(z) = \frac{1}{(z^2-1)^{2019}} \text{ for all } z \in \mathbb C \backslash \{1, -1\}.$$
(b) Show that there exist a set $L \subset \mathbb C$ and a holomorphic function $F$ on $\mathbb C \backslash L$ so that $L$ has Hausdorff dimension $1$, and
$$F'(z) = \frac{1}{(z^2-1)^{2019}} \text{ for all } z \in \mathbb C \backslash L.$$

I didn't manage to figure out (a), I believe (a) should solve after integrate along some curve to arrive in contradiction, but I don't know a good way of changing variables in $z$ to make $z^2-1$ a simple variable. Also I don't know much properties about Hausdorff dimension, but what properties of a Hausdorff dimension $1$ have that makes the holomorphic function exist?

Comment: Don't let the term “Hausdorff dimension” distract you. You can choose $L$ as a suitable line segment.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but what curve should I integrate in (a) to arrive in a contradiction? I think after knowing the curve I'd be able to know what $L$ should I choose in (b)

Comment: *Possible hint:* The residue of $\frac{1}{(z^2-1)^{2019}}$ at $z = \pm 1$ is not zero ...